# Kubernetes Internal Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I use GKE and i'm looking a way to create an internal HTTP L7 ingress with private ip.
The Application of the helm chart nginx provision a public L7 with public ip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate the nginx controller service so the LB provisioner, gives you an internal IP Address.

Try this on your nginx-ingress chart `values.yaml`:

```
controller:
  service:
    annotations:
      cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
```

Reference:

- https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress#configuration
- https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing